# Efficient way of sending the same data to multiple dynamic processes

Tags: shell, system

I have a stream of line-buffered data, and many readers from other processes
The readers need to attach to the system dynamically, they are not known to the process writing the stream

First i tried to read every line and simply send them to a lot of pipes

```sh
#writer
command | while read -r line; do
    printf '%s\n' "$line" | tee listeners/*
done

#reader
mkfifo listeners/1
cat listeners/1
```

But that's consume a lot of CPU

So i though about writing to a file and cleaning it repeatedly

```sh
#writer
command >> file &
while true; do
    : > file
    sleep 1
done

#reader
tail -f -n0 file
```

But sometimes, a line is not read by one or more readers before truncation, making a race condition
Is there a better way on how i could implement this?

Comment: `command | tee listeners/*` why would you loop over the lines? `that's consume a lot of CPU` wow, why? How did you measure it? The usual way is to create pipes on posix compatible systems, on bash the usual way is with `command | tee >(listener1) >(listener2) | listener3`

Comment: New listeners can be created, but the wildcard expansion won't be updated

Comment: Do you need to buffer the lines? Ie. if new listener comes around, does he need to read all the data? You should use `while IFS= read -r line`, otherwise it will remove leading and trailing whitespaces. Probably it's going to be very slow - for each line, you are running 3 processes `read` `printf` and `tee`.

Comment: The data can be unbuffered, but it need to be sent entirely.
I line buffered it so in the worst case it loss the entire line instead of losing just a part of it

Comment: A listener only needs to read the new data, but a while loop is not do-able because of the speed and cpu usage

Comment: You tagged the question with "shell", it implies you want posix only solution? If you would tag with `bash`, your question would reach more people.

Comment: Given focus on performance (implied by CPU utilization and missing lines) - it will help if you will provide short description of the input (frequency, size, messages/second), and consumers (are those scripts ? programs ?). Looks like a simple solution is not going to work - additional details will help suggesting a solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like `pub/sub` to me - see [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Publish%E2%80%93subscribe_pattern).

Basically, new interested parties come along whenever they like and *"subscribe"* to your channel. The process receiving the data then *"publishes"* it, line by line, to that channel.

You can do it with MQTT using **mosquitto** or with **Redis**. Both have command-line interfaces/bindings, as well as Python, C/C++, Ruby, PHP etc. Client and server need not be on same machine, some clients could be elsewhere on the network.

**Mosquitto** example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45458838/2836621).

---

I did a few tests on my Mac with **Redis** pub/sub. The client code in Terminal to subscribe to a channel called `myStream` looks like this:

```
redis-cli SUBSCRIBE myStream
```

I then ran a process to synthesise 10,000 lines like this:

```
time seq 10000  | while read a ; do redis-cli PUBLISH myStream "$a" >/dev/null 2>&1 ; done
```

And that takes 40s, so it does around 250 lines per second, but it has to start a whole new process for each line and create and tear down the connection to Redis... and we don't want to send your CPU mad.

More appropriately for your situation then, here is how you can create a file with 100,000 lines, and read them one at a time, and send them to all your subscribers in Python:

```
# Make a "BigFile" with 100,000 lines
seq 100000 > BigFile
```

and read the lines and publish them with:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import redis

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Redis connection
    r = redis.Redis(host='localhost', port=6379, db=0)

    # Read file line by line...
    with open('BigFile', 'r') as infile:
        for line in infile:
            # Publish the current line to subscribers
            r.publish('myStream', line)
```

The entire 100,000 lines were sent and received in 4s, so 25,000 lines per second. Here is a little recording of it in action. At the top you can see the CPU is not unduly troubled by it. The second window from the top is a client, receiving 100,000 lines and the next window down is a second client. The bottom window shows the server running the Python code above and sending all 100,000 lines in 4s.

[image]

**Keywords**: Redis, mosquitto, pub/sub, publish, subscribe.